# vue.config.js devServer not taken into account

Tags: vue.js, axios

I create a front end vue.js with a springboot microservice as back end.
I'm trying to call my back end (running on another pc 192.168.0.10:9090 in local network) from my front-end vue.js dev server (running localhost:8080).

I configured it in vue.config.js like it's noticed in official website :

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://192.168.0.10:9090',
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Test 2 : same result with

```
 module.exports = {
      devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://192.168.0.10:9090'
      }
    }
```

Test 3 : same result with

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://192.168.0.10:9090',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {               // added this
          '^/api': ''                // added this
        },                           // added this
      }
    }
  }
};
```

my store.js

```
async get(commit, id){     
      var response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url:'/api/getmeeting',
        params: {'guid' : id}
      })
      console.log(this.response)
      return response.data; 
    }
```

Test 2 :

```
  async get(commit, id){     
          var response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url:'/getmeeting',
            params: {'guid' : id}
          })
          console.log(this.response)
          return response.data; 
        }
```

I didn't suceed to use my proxy declared in vue.config.js.

**Problem : All request go to localhost:8080/api/getmeeting?guid=xxxxx whereas it should call 192.168.0.10:9090/getmeeting...**

I read all official [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver), relatives subjects in stack for 8 hours and nothing worked.

So can you give me tips in order to find why my devServer isn't recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`pathRewrite`](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options):

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://192.168.0.10:9090',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {               // added this
          '^/api': ''                // added this
        },                           // added this
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hello, ty for answer, but that always call localhost with this solution, it's like the server don't see the vue.config.js file. I add it in package.json too with the same result. I don't get it.

Comment: Try adding some syntax error to see if the file is being picked up

Comment: good result : "webpack invalid dev server options" error when i replace proxy by prixy. WHat the hell is going on. I guess axios just ignore the vue.config.js i don't know why.

Comment: You shuld make calls to `/api/something`  which will get redirected to `http://192.168.0.10:9090/something`  (or `http://192.168.0.10:9090/api/something` without the `pathRewrite`)

Comment: i actualy call url:'/api/getmeeting', it's not working, it's calling localhost:8080/api/something

Comment: That is correct, axios calls goes to localhost when you call just `/api/getmeeting`. The thing is the proxy server will receive that request (at `localhost:8080`) and will forward it to the configured address (e.g. at `192.168.0.10:9090`). So axios will receive as response to the request to `http://localhost:8080/api/getmeeting` the value that `http://192.168.0.10:9090/getmeeting` returns. If the latter address is unavailable, the devServer will log an error at the console.